# Android browser-like implementation, where do I cache images

Tags: android, caching, persistent

imagine a browser-like implementation and I would like to view html pages offline in this app, where would I store the images?

1. a cache directory within the app's data folder   (not sure if this is persistent data, or if android will wipe it out, or if it will make the app too big)
2. a developer made cache directory on the user's external storage?
3. persistent storage as string objects in a database or in sharedpreferences (again, this may make app too big if cache too large)
4. ??? other solutions?

insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing an app for API lvl 8 (android 2.2) you should use  getExternalCacheDir()
and put your stuff there. Everything in there gets cleaned up(deleted) when the app is uninstalled. If you are just caching for performance i would think that that is to most satisfying result for the user.

Take a look at this for further infos: [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)